# sending a table of data in Microsoft Excel Power Pivot including all calculated fields back to excel as a linked table

Tags: excel, powerpivot, linked-tables

I have used Power Pivot to create some calculated fields from a table of data.

Then I use the modified table, with the calculated fields to create some pivot charts back on the excel workbook.

In the same way I linked the original dataset (excel table) to Power Pivot, I would like to link the table in powerpivot with the calculated fields back to excel. Is this possible?

Comment: i've been told people without powerpivot cant use the slicers because the datasource can't be read, by anything other than powerpivot. so basically analysis in powerpivot are useless, unless you A) have sharepoint to share it, or B everyone you share it with has PowerPivot installed.

Answer (score 0):

**yoshiserry**, the best way to share PowerPivot stuff is PowerView (Excel 2013). If you want to share just the table, regular Excel file should be fine -- people even without PowerPivot installed will be able to work with it (with some limitations).